# Unable to form correct JQ to get proper output from JSON data

Tags: json, jq

I am using JQ Play.

Here is my JSON Data -

```
{
"body": {
"name": "DATATYPES",
"primarykey": [
  "db_number"
],
"members": [
  {
    "name": "db_number",
    "type": "NUMBER"
  },
  {
    "name": "db_date",
    "type": "DATE"
  },
  {
    "name": "db_timestamp",
    "type": "TIMESTAMP(6)"
  },
  {
    "name": "db_timestamp_with_local_time_zone",
    "type": "TIMESTAMP(6) WITH LOCAL TIME ZONE"
  },
  {
    "name": "db_char",
    "type": "CHAR"
  },
  {
    "name": "db_float",
    "type": "FLOAT"
  },
  {
    "name": "db_nchar",
    "type": "NCHAR"
  },
  {
    "name": "db_nvarchar2",
    "type": "NVARCHAR2"
  },
  {
    "name": "db_varchar2",
    "type": "VARCHAR2"
  },
  {
    "name": "db_binary_float",
    "type": "BINARY_FLOAT"
  },
  {
    "name": "db_binary_double",
    "type": "BINARY_DOUBLE"
  },
  {
    "name": "db_timestamp_with_time_zone",
    "type": "TIMESTAMP(6) WITH TIME ZONE"
  },
  {
    "name": "db_interval_year_to_month",
    "type": "INTERVAL YEAR(2) TO MONTH"
  },
  {
    "name": "db_interval_day_to_second",
    "type": "INTERVAL DAY(2) TO SECOND(6)"
  },
  {
    "name": "db_long",
    "type": "LONG"
  },
  {
    "name": "db_blob",
    "type": "BLOB"
  },
  {
    "name": "db_clob",
    "type": "CLOB"
  },
  {
    "name": "db_boolean",
    "type": "CHAR"
  }
  ],
  "links": [
  {
    "rel": "collection",
    "href": "https://tdcvm28s16.bcone.com:7002/ords/testords/metadata-catalog/",
    "mediaType": "application/json"
  },
  {
    "rel": "canonical",
    "href": "https://tdcvm28s16.bcone.com:7002/ords/testords/metadata-catalog/datatypes/",
    "mediaType": "application/json"
  },
  {
    "rel": "alternate",
    "href": "https://tdcvm28s16.bcone.com:7002/ords/testords/open-api-catalog/datatypes/",
    "mediaType": "application/openapi+json"
  },
  {
    "rel": "describes",
    "href": "https://tdcvm28s16.bcone.com:7002/ords/testords/datatypes/"
  }
  ]
  }
  }
```

My First JQ -

```
{"parameters":([.body.primarykey[0]] | reduce .[] as $item ({}; .[$item] = ""))}
```

Output -

```
{
"parameters": {
"db_number": ""
}
}
```

Here, my requirement is - I want type of primary also in parameters in output by comparing it with matching record from members.

My expected output is -

```
{
"parameters": {
"db_number": "number"
}
}
```

Please help me with correct JQ that will work in jqplay.org

My Second JQ -

```
.body.primarykey[] as $k | {  parameters: {($k): "" }, body: (.body.members | map( 
select(.name != $k) | {(.name): .type |ascii_downcase}) | add)}
```

Here, my requirement is - I want same parameters as above with type of primarykey along with body which eliminates matching primarykey from body.

My expected output is -

```
{
"parameters": {
"db_number": "number"
},
"body": {
"db_date": "date",
"db_timestamp": "timestamp(6)",
"db_timestamp_with_local_time_zone": "timestamp(6) with local time zone",
"db_char": "char",
"db_float": "float",
"db_nchar": "nchar",
"db_nvarchar2": "nvarchar2",
"db_varchar2": "varchar2",
"db_binary_float": "binary_float",
"db_binary_double": "binary_double",
"db_timestamp_with_time_zone": "timestamp(6) with time zone",
"db_interval_year_to_month": "interval year(2) to month",
"db_interval_day_to_second": "interval day(2) to second(6)",
"db_long": "long",
"db_blob": "blob",
"db_clob": "clob",
"db_boolean": "char"
}
}
```

Please help me with correct JQ that will work in jqplay.org

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're losing reference if you cut too early, and still to get the value you need you'd then have to iterate over `.members` again, find the right key, adjust the case again, etc.

Here's a restructured version of your original attempt which just groups the members by containedness in the primary keys array, then assigns each section to to the right keys in the output object.

```bash
.body | . as {$primarykey} | .members
| map(.value = (.type | ascii_downcase))
| group_by(IN(.name; $primarykey[])) | map(from_entries)
| {parameters: last, body: first}
```

```json
{
  "parameters": {
    "db_number": "number"
  },
  "body": {
    "db_date": "date",
    "db_timestamp": "timestamp(6)",
    "db_timestamp_with_local_time_zone": "timestamp(6) with local time zone",
    "db_char": "char",
    "db_float": "float",
    "db_nchar": "nchar",
    "db_nvarchar2": "nvarchar2",
    "db_varchar2": "varchar2",
    "db_binary_float": "binary_float",
    "db_binary_double": "binary_double",
    "db_timestamp_with_time_zone": "timestamp(6) with time zone",
    "db_interval_year_to_month": "interval year(2) to month",
    "db_interval_day_to_second": "interval day(2) to second(6)",
    "db_long": "long",
    "db_blob": "blob",
    "db_clob": "clob",
    "db_boolean": "char"
  }
}
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/sw5VuVYgGiA)

Comment: hello @pmf, can we achieve this without using "IN" keyword / function ? Because the framework which I am using doesn't support this "IN". So is there any alternate JQ to get same desired output ?

Comment: Change `IN(.name; $primarykey[])` to `any(.name; . == $primarykey[])`

Comment: hello @pmf, please provide JQ for first expected output also. Please modify my first JQ according to my first expected output.

Comment: @sujay777 I thought this was obvious. Your two expected outputs only differ in the presence or absence of the `body` field. The solution provided contains it, so for the other one just don't produce it (i.e. replace `{parameters: last, body: first}` with `{parameters: last}`, [Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/I7bgwat3aUX))

Comment: Thanks @pmf, now its working fine with both cases.

Answer (score 2):

For your first result :

```
jq '.body
   |( .members | map(.value=(.type|ascii_downcase)) | from_entries ) as $mapping
   |{parameters:(.primarykey | map({key:., value:$mapping[.]}) | from_entries)
}' input.json
```

then second result :

```
jq '.body
   |( .members | map(.value=(.type|ascii_downcase)) | from_entries ) as $mapping
   |{parameters:(.primarykey | map({key:., value:$mapping[.]}) | from_entries),
     body:$mapping
}' input.json
```

[jq-play](https://jqplay.org/s/b7sHXWWwBLK)

Comment: please provide link of Jqplay.org , above jq's are not working for me in JQ Play.